# `viewForFooterInSection:` not showing custom view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have this custom view in a `UIViewController` class:

```
let footerView: CustomView = {
    let footerView = CustomView()
    footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    return footerView
}()
```

Then I have:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    footerView.title = getString(TITLE)
    return footerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

But nothing is displayed. However, if I make that `footer` view a subview of the viewController's `view` instead of footer view of the table I have, it is displayed.

What could I be missing? I don't figure it out... Thank you